# Draw a flowchart with decision box with smartdiagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

There is a way to draw a flowchart with decision nodes, like this, using smartdiagram or something else?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 4):

### *In my opinion, I ought not answer this question. Caveat emptor.*

For one thing, my answer is likely to be of little help unless you want precisely this with almost no changes, or you could actually do this yourself but just wanted somebody else to do your work for free. Only in the second case are you likely to be able to modify it to your needs without actually doing some work to figure out how things work, which you could have done anyhow.

For another different but related thing, my answer contains zero explanation because I simply have no idea what needs explaining or where you are starting from. That is, I have no idea what the obstacle is to your drawing this yourself. Since I cannot explain everything here and have no idea what needs explaining, I can't usefully explain anything at all.

I really answered this because I wanted to play with the `graphs` syntax without the `graphsdrawing` code, which depends on LuaTeX. If you know nothing about PGF/Ti*k*Z, this is not a good place to start. In that case, start with the `positioning` library without `graphs` or try the deprecated `chains` library if feeling especially adventurous.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,graphs,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    >=Stealth,
    thick,
    base/.style={draw=#1, thick, inner color=#1!60, outer color=#1!75},
    bb/.style={base=Cerulean, text height=.75em, text depth=.25em},
    gc/.style={base=ForestGreen, circle},
    rc/.style={base=WildStrawberry, circle},
    yd/.style={base=Periwinkle, diamond, align=center, aspect=1.75},
  ]
  \graph [grow right=20mm] {
   G/""[gc] -> Aardvarks[bb] -- L/""[coordinate] -!- Bananas[bb] -- R/""[coordinate] -!- Cabbages[bb] -> Babbage[bb] -> Enormity[bb] -> RC/"" [rc];
   L -> BB/"Blue\\Baguettes"[above=15mm of L, yd];
   R -> HH/"Hysterical\\Holograms"[below=-10mm of R, yd];
  };
  \foreach \i/\j\k/\l/\m/\n/\o in {BB/Aardvarks/Bananas/Superfluous/-40/Antiquities/-140,HH/Bananas/Cabbages/Expeditious/30/Ambiguities/150}
  {
    \draw [->] (\i) -| (\j) node [midway, anchor=\m] {\l};
    \draw [->] (\i) -| (\k) node [midway, anchor=\o] {\n};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: cabbages and things]

Answer (score -1):

You're going to want to use [Tikz](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/08/29/tikz-series-pt3.html):

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
```

Note that the flow is downward in the linked example, but you can easily change this to right-flowing by changing the `below of=x` to `right of=x` to tell the node where to position itself.

To draw a decision block, define a Tikz style like:

```
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=yellow!30]
```

Comment: Both `arrows` and `\tikzstyle` are deprecated. Also, answers which rely on the content of external links - especially when the content is outdated - are discouraged. It would be better to include a proper, current answer here or to mark this as a duplicate of another question on this site, if such exists.